# Exec jQuery Chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I try exec chosen(). lib from: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

But when i try clikt to dropdown nothing happens.

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
   });
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mrmoonlv/fwnUd/)** is my demo.

What I`m doing wrong?
Thanks, Karlis

Comment: Are you include chosen js file

Comment: @TamilSelvan Yes ofcourse: chosen.jquery.min.js

Comment: see console and display the error it shows

Comment: @TamilSelvan no errors on firebug.

Comment: check ur chosen css is correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to implement chosen plugin as

JFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/fwnUd/3/

(I think you copied the source code from chosen offical demo page and it not works  because of some css issue)
.

Change to

```
<select tabindex="-1" style="width: 350px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Country...">
```

to

```
<select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Country...">
```